# What's +25 in my answer?

Tags: discussion, questions

I've recently received 25 reputation by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24462355/2729109). And I've found +25 mark beside answer. What's this?

Comment: it is a bounty.  hold the mouse over it and it tell you so.  *Apparently* the user did not accept your answer so you only get have the originally offered amount simply for having the highest upvoted answer.

Comment: The answer had to be posted after the bounty was started (cc @Plutonix)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You received half of a +50 rep bounty. From the [bounty privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties):

> If you do not award the bounty within 24 hours of the bounty period ending, **half the bounty value** will be automatically awarded to the **top voted answer posted after the bounty start**, provided it has a score of **at least 2**. If no new answer matches this requirement, no reputation will be awarded at all, and the reputation used on the bounty will be lost forever.

(emph mine)